# mapping the data of the child form on the parent form symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have created a Form Type that adds an autocomplete feature for Entities, however it requires some configuration for every Entity, i.e: I have to pass the configuration to the options array, so I decided to make a new FormType for each Entity using the AutoCompleteType I created and reuse them.However I want these Formtypes i.e: the ones for each particular Entity, to return the Entity when `getData()` is called on it, what happens now is that I have to first retrieve the field of ParentForm containing the `AutoCompleteType` then call `getData()` to retrieve my Entity.How can I map this information directly on the ParentForm?

```
//the FormType of Some Entity using the AutoComplete
...
class SomeEntityAutoCompleteType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array options){
       $builder->add('some_entity', 'entity_autocomplete', array(...));
    }
}


    //the controller
    public function someAction(){
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new SomeEntityAutoCompleteType());
        ...
        //I want the below line to return my entity
        $form->getData();
        //but I have to use this one right now
        $form['some_entity']->getData()
    }
```

*note*: I haven't actually tested the other approach but from what I understand of the Symfony Form Component it should be the way I described;

Comment: I think I have to use a DataTransformer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the parent type of my `SomeEntityAutoCompleteType` to the main autocomplete type I had created and configuring the options using the `setDefaultOptions()` method.

```
//SomeEntityAutoCompleteType
public function setDefaultOption(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(...);
}

public function getParent(){
    return "autocomplete_type";//this is the main autocomplete type I mentioned
}
```